# how to subtract records coming from one query from the records that is coming from another query?

Tags: sql-server

these are the two queries, returning multiple records, so is there any solution to subtract each row data of one result from another result?

query1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As AbhidayNotPaidSansthan
 FROM PanjikaranMaster GROUP BY Zila
```

query2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as anps FROM AbhidayMaster,PanjikaranMaster
    WHERE PanjikaranMaster.OfficeRegId=AbhidayMaster.OfficeRegId AND
    AbhidayMaster.DipositDate Between ('2012-09-19') AND ('2012-09-24')
GROUP BY PanjikaranMaster.Zila
```

Comment: Can you add the ouput of each query and the desired outcome you are expecting?

Comment: can you be a little more specific what you want ?

Comment: result of 1st query: result of 2nd query: i want the output as
AbhidayNotPaidSansthan anps                 Difference
5                 2                 3 i.e.(5-2)
2                 1                1 i.e.(1-1)

Comment: And how do you know which values from query 1 to subtract from with other values from query 2 ?? As is, both queries just return a bunch of numbers....

Comment: @marc_s:
both the queries has grouped by 'Zila' field, so 1st record should be subtracted from 1st, 2nd from 2nd, and so on

Comment: @user1673240: but you should **never** rely on the sequence of the values; what if one value of `Zila` is missing from one of the two queries? If you need to match rows - return something to match by, e.g. the `Zila` column!

Comment: @marc_s:
ok.. if i return 'Zila' column, then how to subtract records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this query, it will solve your problem:

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.cnt,0) -  ISNULL(b.cnt,0) AS CNT,a.Zila
FROM
    (SELECT Zila,COUNT(*) as cnt As AbhidayNotPaidSansthan
    FROM PanjikaranMaster GROUP BY Zila) a
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Zila,COUNT(*) as cnt FROM AbhidayMaster,PanjikaranMaster
    WHERE PanjikaranMaster.OfficeRegId=AbhidayMaster.OfficeRegId AND
    AbhidayMaster.DipositDate Between ('2012-09-19') AND ('2012-09-24')
    GROUP BY PanjikaranMaster.Zila) b 
    ON a.Zila = b.Zila
```

I have done similar test in **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ae18/4)**